# Git Diff between two commits/changeset without including merge commit changes

Tags: git, git-diff

How to take combined Git diff between 2 commit changesets without including the changes made by merge commits.
For ex :

Commit-1a
File - `gitdiff.js` 
Changes

```
function check(){ 
            var a=10;  
            console.log(a);  
        }
```

Commit-2b (Merge commit)
File - `gitdiff.js`
Changes

```
function merge(){ 
            console.log(“inside merge”);   
        }   
        function mergechange(){ 
            console.log(“inside mergechange”);  
        }
```

Commit-3c
File - `gitdiff.js`
Changes

```
function lastfn(){  
            console.log(“inside lastfn”);   
        }
```

File Content after 3 commits

```
function merge(){   
            console.log(“inside merge”);   
        }       
        function check(){   
            var a=10;   
            console.log(a);    
        }
    
function mergechange(){    
            console.log(“inside mergechange”);    
        }    
        function lastfn(){    
            console.log(“inside lastfn”);    
        }
```

When I am giving git diff between commit 1a and commit 3c, I want the output diff like the following. 
Git diff commit-1a commit-3c
File - `gitdiff.js`
Changes

```
function check(){    
    var a=10;    
    console.log(a);    
}   
function lastfn(){    
    console.log(“inside lastfn”);    
}
```

Is there anyway to get the output like the above without including the merge changes ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you want.

Git stores project states, and `git diff` can only show changes between project states. For `git diff` it is totally irrelevant what the relation between the two states is, and whether there are any other project states between them, or whether one of them is a merge.